# Типы значений и ссылочные типы

Tags: c#

Переменная `xStr` - ссылочный тип или нет ?

Почему переменную `xStr` - не затрагивают изменения как объект `stringBuilder` ?

В метод всё таки попадает копия значения, а не копия ссылки ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int xInt = 0;
        string xStr = "0";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new("0");

        TestChange(xInt);
        TestChange(xStr);
        TestChange(stringBuilder);

        Console.WriteLine(xInt);
        Console.WriteLine(xStr);
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
    }

    static void TestChange(int xInt) 
    {
        xInt = 1;
    }

    static void TestChange(string xStr)
    {
        xStr = "1";
    }

    static void TestChange(StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        stringBuilder.Clear();
        stringBuilder.Append("1");
    }
}
```

> **В консоли вывод:**
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 1

**UPD**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int xInt = 0;
        string xStr = "0";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new("0");

        TestChange(xInt);
        TestChange(xStr);
        TestChange(stringBuilder);

        Console.WriteLine(xInt);
        Console.WriteLine(xStr);
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
    }

    static void TestChange(int xInt) 
    {
        xInt = 1;
    }

    static void TestChange(string xStr)
    {
        xStr = null;
    }

    static void TestChange(StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        stringBuilder = null;
    }
}
```

> **В консоли вывод:**
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0

**UPD: Разобрался в понимании - спасибо!**

Comment: для чистоты эксперимента третий метод должен был быть таким: `stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("1")`. Странно почему во всех подобных вопросах, выполняются разные действия и удивляются почему результат оказывается разным ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Добавил UPD: Сейчас лучше вариант для чистоты ?

Comment: Обрати внимание, что теперь нет никакой разницы, все три функции, работают абсолютно одинаково, и результат, абсолютно одинаковый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подумайте о разнице между

```
variable = another_value;
```

и

```
variable.modifyVariableContent();
```

внутри функции, куда передается `variable`.

Comment: Добавил UPD: Сейчас лучше вариант для чистоты ?

Comment: @Vipz Я не понимаю что значит "лучше вариант для чистоты".  Вам что-то непонятно в ответе?

Comment: Да - сначала не мог понять, запутался в ошибках, но по вашим отрывкам выпутался и разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: @Vipz Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

В языке C# тип String является неизменяемым. Это означает, что, когда вы присваиваете одной переменной новое значение, то создаётся новый объект типа String и сохраняется в этой пременной, а прежний объект теряется, если на него не указывают другие ссылки.

Comment: "String является неизменяемым" - В данном случае это не имеет значения.

Comment: @Igor блин, а я подумал что это +/- хоть какой то ответ на мои вопросы. А как тогда в действительности ? Просто все что то только примерами без объяснений отвечают.

Comment: @Vipz Я уже написал, что Вы делаете в одном и в другом случае. Вам что-то непонятно в ответе?

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы Int менялся, его надо по ссылке передавать, а не по значению:

```
static void TestChange(ref int xInt) 
{
    xInt = 1;
}
```

Иначе создаётся локальная переменная типа int в функции. Согласно ответу @SergeyK, со стрингами та же история.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
        [Test]
        public static void Test()
        {
            int xInt = 1;
            string xStr = "1";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new("1");

            TestChange(ref xInt);
            TestChange(ref xStr);
            TestChange(ref stringBuilder);

            Console.WriteLine(xInt);
            Console.WriteLine(xStr);
            Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
        }
        static void TestChange<T>(ref T value)
        {
            dynamic d = null;
            if (typeof(string) == typeof(T))
                d = "0";
            else if (typeof(int) == typeof(T)) 
                d = 0;
            else if (typeof(StringBuilder) == typeof(T))
                d = new StringBuilder("0");
            value = d;
        }
```

Standard Output:
0
0
0

Comment: вопрос был не про инт а про стринг. С интом все и так понятно ибо это валью тайп. А вот его удивляет что стринг ведет себя так же как инт, хотя это вроде как референс.